# Half color icons on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a fixed transparent header that has series of icons. By default the icons are white but when I scroll down the page, the icons change color so that they can be seen, e.g become black when hovering a white background, etc.

I achieve this by applying a data attribute to each section of the page:

`data-header-class="header--white"`

and then using jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.sect').each(function () {
        var w = $(window).scrollTop();
        var t = $(this).offset().top - (40 + 32);
        if (w > t) {
            $('.header').removeClass (function (index, css) {
                return (css.match (/(^|\s)header--\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
            });
            $('.header').addClass( $(this).attr('data-header-class') );
        }
    });
});
```

I apply a CSS class to header to swap the colours. Here is an example: http://dev.driz.co.uk/iconbleed/

I'm using a combination of font icons and custom CSS to create the header icons.

However what I want to do is make the icons half bleed the colors of the sections that they are overlaying **as you scroll**. So for example, if I'm half way into the white area, half the icons change color to black, whilst the other half remains white still (see screenshot below). The icons should change color in relation to the amount they have bleeded.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by having a different image in each row that is hidden when it 'overflows' the parent div?  Not the most elegant way to do this but solves the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/vLLwhzqL/

html:

```
<div class="row1">
        <div class="IMG1">
            ICON
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <div class="IMG2">
            ICON
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row1">
        <div class="IMG3">
            ICON
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <div class="IMG4">
            ICON
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row1">
        <div class="IMG5">
            ICON
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <div class="IMG6">
            ICON
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.row1{
    background-color:black;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-left:20px;
    font-size:50px;
    color:white;
}

.row2{
    background-color:white;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-left:20px;
    font-size:50px;
    color:black;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var Scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.IMG1').css({'margin-top':(Scroll+20)});
    $('.IMG2').css({'margin-top':(Scroll-480)});
    $('.IMG3').css({'margin-top':(Scroll-980)});
    $('.IMG4').css({'margin-top':(Scroll-1480)});
    $('.IMG5').css({'margin-top':(Scroll-1980)});
    $('.IMG6').css({'margin-top':(Scroll-2480)});

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var Scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.IMG1').css({'margin-top':(Scroll+20)});
        $('.IMG2').css({'margin-top':(Scroll-480)});
        $('.IMG3').css({'margin-top':(Scroll-980)});
        $('.IMG4').css({'margin-top':(Scroll-1480)});
        $('.IMG5').css({'margin-top':(Scroll-1980)});
        $('.IMG6').css({'margin-top':(Scroll-2480)});

    });
});
```

Comment: This could work. I'll have a play using this as a base. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, hope it goes well.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest for what you want. I applied it to icon-search, for example:

```
.icon-search:before {
    background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #ccc 0%, #ccc 50%, #555 50%, #555 100% );
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS gradients

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

**Example**: Half black, half grey:

```
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,c4c4c4+100 */
background: #000000; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%, #c4c4c4 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#000000), color-stop(100%,#c4c4c4)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#c4c4c4 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#c4c4c4 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#c4c4c4 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #000000 0%,#c4c4c4 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#c4c4c4',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

Needed additionally for IE9:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: How would I apply the gradient in relation to the scroll amount? It wouldn't always be a clear 50/50 %

Comment: Yea, it would be 50/50. For the scroll amount you would need to calculate the position and generate the CSS on the fly. Is it worth it at the end of the day?

Comment: What about if you snapped the view ```x pixels``` down instead with a little animation when the css change appears?